# jQuery like config passing

Tags: javascript

i have done this so far:

```
api_configs({
  color:'grey',
  type:'fast'
});

function api_configs(confs){     
  for(var c in confs)
  {
    alert(c);
  }  
}
```

It works fine, but the alert only returns color, and type.
How to parse the full value?

Comment: `alert( c + ': ' + confs[c] )`

Comment: Awsome :) Thanks! Post as an answer, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to access the value:

```
alert(c + ': ' + confs[c]);
```